# ASP.NET Boilerplate which is better way to sync tables

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I am developing with `ASP.NET Boilerplate`, and here is my scenario

I have a ABP project with full database with `AbpTenants` and `AbpOrganizationUnits`, now I create another project which will only contains table `Order`, but I need the `AbpOrganizationUnits` data which is only availbe in previous project.

What is the better way to get `AbpOrganizationUnits` in my `Order` project? I have a `OrganizationUnit Name` in my order, and I want to set it value.

Comment: Add a reference to the project.

Comment: I did not mean `OrganizationUnit Name`, I mean I want all the OrganizationUnit data in first project from second project.

Comment: Connect to the same database?